# Covering deficits with values with different weights

Tags: probability, statistics, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, average

SO I have a couple of assessments with specific weights as follows:

- Assignment 1: 5% => Mark 60%
- Assignment 2: 5% => Mark 53%
- Assignment 3: 5%
- Assignment 4: 5%
- Test 1: 30% => 47%
- Test 2: 30%
- Practical 1: 10% => 66%
- Practical 2: 10%

Currently the average of the assessments with marks is 52.7%. However My target is to get a final mark of 60%, therefore i am currently 7.3% below my target.How do i assign this deficit to the remaining assessments taking into consideration the different weights of these assessments?

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at it like you need a total of $60$ percentage points.  Right now you have $$.05(60)+.05(53)+.3(47)+.1(66)=26.35\text{ percentage points}$$

So, you need to now achieve $$.05(\text{A3})+.05(\text{A4})+.3(\text{T2})+.10(\text{P2})$$ such that the sum of that expression is $33.65$.

If you are looking for what single grade could you score on them all and achieve your goal, you can simplify it to $$.5A=33.65\\A=67.3$$

But obviously you could do slightly better on the test and much worse on the others and pass that way too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But now if i share the deficit of 7.3% points among the remaining assessments as follows i get (A3)60.365, (A4)60.365, (T2)62.19 and (P2)60.73. the weighted total of these is 30.45625. If i add this weighted total to the already attained 26.35, it does not add up to 60%, the minimum.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for?  The 7.3% deficit was already taken into account to get the 67.3% required.

Comment: I understand. But i want to allocated the deficit to the remaining assessments according to their weights, so that i know how much needs to be attained for each assessment so that i end up at a minimum of 60%. Like you pointed out, i need to get a combined mark of 67.3% in all the remaining assessments, but how do i calculate the mark for the separate assessments, according to their weights.

Comment: There are an infinite way you could allocate your scores.  What is your criteria?  For example, you could get a zero on the two assignments, a 100 on the test and a 33.7 on the practical and that would pass the course.  Or you could get a 50 on the assignments, a 70 on the test and a 77 on the practical and pass.  Or if you wanted to get the same proportions, you could make a 67.3 on each.

Comment: Did you mean you want your deviations from 60% on each mark to be in a proportion of .05/.05/.30/.10?  if that is the case you would want to score 61.7, 61.7, 70.4, 63.5 (approximately)

Comment: Yes i mean the last one. But if im not being much of a problem can you please tell me how you arrived to 61.7, 61.7, 70.4 and 63.5. When i do the calculation to allocate the deficit i am getting 60.37, 60.37, 62.19 and 60.73 using the propotions. @turkeyhundt

Comment: I solved it numerically using excel.